# Indexing into a list of zoo objects

Tags: r, time-series, zoo

If I have a list of zoo objects, how do I go about referring to particular values by list index([[]]) and date? For example:

```
require("zoo")
require("tseries")
require("lubridate")

z = zoo(c(1,2,3), as.Date(c("2000/1/1", "2000/2/1", "2000/3/1")))
z1 = zoo(c(1,2,3), as.Date(c("2000/1/1", "2000/2/1", "2000/3/1")))
z2 = zoo(c(10,20,30), as.Date(c("2000/1/1", "2000/2/1", "2000/3/1")))
z3 = zoo(c(100,200,300), as.Date(c("2000/1/1", "2000/2/1", "2000/3/1")))
> l = list(z1,z2,z3)
> l
[[1]]
2000-01-01 2000-02-01 2000-03-01 
         1          2          3 

[[2]]
2000-01-01 2000-02-01 2000-03-01 
        10         20         30 

[[3]]
2000-01-01 2000-02-01 2000-03-01 
       100        200        300
```

My goal is to return a value for each row that has the column number of the month from the index. Desired output on above data would be:

`1, 20, 300` (can be a zoo object, vector, whatever is easiest to show). I'll coerce it how I need.

The way I've been trying to code it is (among others):

```
monthNumbs = month(index(l[[1]]))
l[[monthNumbs]][index(l)]
```

I know this is structurally incorrect; but it's how I'm viewing the data structures. Any help would be great...

Comment: I don't understand how do you get `1, 20, 30` , Do you mean `1, 20, 300`. can you clarify this?

Comment: Does all your zoo objects have the same index?

Comment: @agstudy some are longer by a few... 12 zoos with lengths varying from 155-162. All are monthly; where they overlap, the index values are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I well understood your question , I think you can do this for example:

```
## loop through the index of the list
## for each zoo object l[[x]]  you get months index
## and you compare it to current index
unlist(lapply(seq_along(l),
        function(x)l[[x]][month(index(l[[x]]))==x]))
[1]   1  20 300
```

**EDIT** Another alternative using `xts` package:

If all your `zoo` objects have teh same index, you can merge them to get a matrix structure:

```
library(xts)
mm <- do.call(merge,lapply(l,as.xts))
           c.1..2..3. c.10..20..30. c.100..200..300.
2000-01-01          1            10              100
2000-02-01          2            20              200
2000-03-01          3            30              300
```

Then you get the diagonales values like this :

```
as.matrix(mm)[col(mm)==row(mm)]
```